# "mostly negative economic impact" vs "negative economic impact for the most part"

Tags: comparison

I wanna discuss the difference between the following two sentences:

1. The policy will have mostly negative economic impacts.
2. The policy will have negative economic impacts for the most part.

Would you please help comment on my following interpretation?

In **1.**, "mostly" modifies negative. So the policy's other impacts, eg political or environmental, are unaddressed.

In **2.**, "for the most part" modifies either economic impact or the whole sentence; either way, the sentence basically means the negative economic impact outweighs other impacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I wanna discuss the difference between the following two sentences:**

> 1. The policy will have mostly negative economic impacts.

> 2. The policy will have negative economic impacts for the most part.

---

First I am going to correct the English in both sentences

1. The policy will have a mostly negative economic impact.
2. The policy will have a negative economic impact for the most part.

---

> In 1., "mostly" modifies negative. So the policy's other impacts, eg political or environmental, are unaddressed.

A1. This is incorrect. What the sentence means is "**The policy will have a mainly negative economic influence**". It also implies that **it will not be totally negative**.

> In 2., "for the most part" modifies either economic impact or the whole sentence; either way, the sentence basically means the negative economic impact outweighs other impacts.

A2. This is also incorrect. Once again what the sentence means is "**The policy will have a mainly negative economic influence**" The use of the idiom "for the most part" just means **mainly** so the answer is as for In 1.

> Meaning of Idiom ‘For the Most Part’; For the most part means in general; usually; mostly Ref [**Idioms Online**](https://www.idioms.online/for-the-most-part/)

**mostly** adverb; mainly: Ref CED [Mostly](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mostly)

**impact**; to have an influence on something: Ref CED [Impact](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impact)